# Screen blending and normal blending

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have a 2 smart objects in photoshop, one being a find edges set to screen for blending and the other, a crystalized image set to normal blending. When I set the blending, I can only see the screen blending, and if i set the picture to screen, I can't see anything. Here's an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wn66P.png) I hope this makes sense, and someone can be able to help me! Thanks

Comment: This is tutorial step 7: "Add a new 'Invert' Adjustment layer and create a clipping mask so that it only effects 'Layer 2'. Do the same with a Hue/Saturation adjustment layer and move the Saturation value down to -100"                                                                                                         Did you clip the Invert and Saturation adjustment layers?

Comment: Yes I did. I dont know whats going wrong